# selenium grid with capybara rspec

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

I am trying to setup selenium grid to achieve parallel execution of my tests. First, I'll explain the my current scenario.

1. I have my fully functional test suite written in capybara.
2. I need to execute all my tests in multiple browsers.
3. I created a setup for selenium hub and node
4. I can launch my browsers but not executing my testcases

My goal is to run my tests on multiple browsers simultaneously. I missing a part where I need to configure my tests to run in parallel. there are some examples about grid setup in the web, as I am using different framework I couldn't relate to my scenario.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no grid setup which allows you to run tests parallely (as far as I know), you should set your parallel execution through capybara.

Comment: How can I do with capybara ??

Comment: Don't know, I never worked with capybara. Check this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565844/running-parallel-selenium-tests-with-capybara